# In order to check if a field is required or not, is the result of isNillable method sufficient?

Tags: apex, required-field, describefieldresult

Accordingly to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isNillable) of `isNillable` method of `Schema.DescribeFieldResult` class:

> **isNillable()**
>
> Returns *true* if the field is nillable, *false* otherwise. A
>   nillable field can have empty content. A non-nillable field must have
>   a value for the object to be created or saved.

Is it correct to state that a necessary and sufficient condition for a field to be required is that `isNillable` method returns *false*?
I'm pretty sure that it is a necessary condition but not so sure that it is also a sufficient condition if we take into account also validation rules and triggers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First Approach -**
For the field to be required it has to meet 3 conditions:

1. is Creatable
2. is NOT Nillable
3. is NOT Default on create

So your if condition should be as following:

```
if(field.isCreateable() && !field.isNillable() && !field.isDefaultedOnCreate()){
// your code
}
```

Once ’field’ is an element while of DescribeFieldResult.

**Second Approach -** to cover code in a try catch block. Into the ’try’ you can insert the Object without the field you want to check, if an exception is thrown, check which required fields are mentioned in the error message.
In this approach, you have to delete the record once it succeeds to be inserted.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer with some explanations on why the other two conditions should be checked?

Comment: Also, could you please spend a word about validation rules? I think that it's not possible to check them from apex but I'm not sure.

Comment: @gvgramazio About your first question. For example, CreatedDate is not a nillable field since it has value once record is created, but he is not a required field for the client. To avoid these fields, you should add the two conditions I’ve mentioned.

Comment: @gvgramazio About your second question. Validation rule is a problematic issue. Your valudation rule includes formula which avoids saving or creating a record once it meets the conditions. You can retrieve the formula using apex, but you can't really know what the formula means in run time. For covering this scenario, the workaround I suggest is the second approach I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Or, instead of a try-catch, you can use allOrNone=false to make sure you get all the errors.

Comment: N.B. try-catch will litter the debug log with spurious exceptions that are benignly processed

Comment: I wonder if this is how the FieldSetMember.getDBRequired value is calculated https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_FieldSetMember.htm#apex_Schema_FieldSetMember_getDBRequired

Comment: @sfdcfox, I understood that a DmlException would include all the errors anyway, via the various getters provided?

Comment: I think that I will use a mix of the two solutions with a slightly addition. First check the three condition and autofill - with some hardcoded default values - the required fields, then use a try-catch block in conjunction with save points to assert that there aren't any other mandatory conditions without actually save nothing.

Comment: @gvgramazio sounds good..